# ASP.NET error message if textbox is empty or too short

Tags: asp.net, messagebox

I have tried following code however there was no change and it doesnt show the error message.

```
  if (TextBox1.Text.Length<500 || TextBox1.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Scripts","<script>alert('Input is empty or too short.');</script>");


        }
```

Comment: Apart from the answer below, which is nice, when you want to validate so that a textbox isn't empty I'd recommend     string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) instead of .Length == 0

Answer (score 1):

The example below will execute a javascript function which will check for validity of `TextBox1` and display an error message if the length is less than 500.If the length is 500 or more the validation passed and the server side `Button1_Click` will execute.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CheckValidInput() {
            var textLength = $("#TextBox1").val().length;

            if (textLength < 500) {
                alert("Input is empty or too short.");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return CheckValidInput()" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
```